# How to set Child div width 100% while parent over flow?

Tags: html, css

How to set top panel width (red color in the following image) always set to 100%
[image]

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azzi/aqx5Ln90/)

this is my code. I dont need to increase the parent width and the panel should increase the size.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <style type="text/css">
            .lib{
             border: 2px solid black;
             width: 200px;
             height: 300px;
             background-color: yellow;
             overflow: auto;

            }            
            .panel{
                background-color: red;
                width: 100%;
                height: 20px;
            }

        </style>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="lib">
            <div class="panel"></div>

            <ol>
                <li>test test test test test test test test test </li>
                <li>test testtesttesttesttesttest testtesttesttest </li>
                <li>test testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest </li>
                <li>test testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest </li>
                <li>test testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please set up a http://jsFiddle.net fot this kind of Questions

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your js. http://jsfiddle.net/gnf4p3x8/

```
var scrollWidth = $('.lib')[0].scrollWidth;
console.log(scrollWidth)
$('.panel').width(scrollWidth + 'px');
```

If you are wondering why not css...It's because the div is already taking the parents width which is 100%. What you need here is width more than the parent's.
You can try providing width more than 100% i.e. 110%, 120% etc it will work. But if you need exact width then js is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
  .lib{
         border: 2px solid black;
         width: 200px;
         height: 300px;
         background-color: yellow;
         overflow: auto;

        }            
        .panel{
            background-color: red;
            width:  132%;
            height: 20px;

        }
```

this is not a proper way, you can do it with jsthat will be better then this one. this is the fiddle....http://jsfiddle.net/r5g9hpju/

Comment: hello please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/r5g9hpju/2/  not good think apply width 132% .

Answer (score 0):

```css
.lib{
             border: 2px solid black;
             width: 200px;
             height: 300px;
             background-color: yellow;
             overflow:auto;
             word-wrap: break-word; 
            }            
.panel{
                background-color: red;
                width:100%;
                height: 20px;
       }
```

```html
<div class="lib">
            <div class="panel"></div>

            <ol>
                <li>test test test test test test test test test </li>
                <li>test testtesttesttesttesttest testtesttesttest </li>
                <li>test testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest </li>
                <li>test testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest </li>
                <li>test testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
```

Comment: actually <li> should be in single line.